# Call class methods inline to create a new object

Tags: ruby

Trying to figure out if I can pass arguments to a class without creating a new object. I tried as below

*Filename: display.rb*

```
class Print
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end 
  def disp
    p @name
  end
end

init = Print.new(ARGV[0])
init.disp
```

*Terminal*

```
> ruby display.rb "ross"
# => "ross"
```

**[EDIT]** I don't want to call `init = Print.new(ARGV[0])` and `init.disp` in the file; instead, I want to pass it as command line argument `ruby display.rb "ross"`, and it should display the name. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to call `Print.new`?

Comment: @stefan: I don't want to use Class.new in the file. I want to pass arguments to this file together with the filename and the class should get initilized.

Comment: In order to initialize a class, you call .new on it.  If you don't want to initialize a class, you don't call .new on it.  More correctly, an instance of the class will get initialized if you call .new on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea. Load the rb file and execute some inline ruby afterwards:

```
ruby -r"./display.rb" -e "Print.new('ross').disp"
```

Comment: This does not adhere to the "I don't want to use .new" part of the question.  Unless the part of assigning the variable `init` was what was wanted to be avoided.  Still not quite clear.

Comment: @vgoff OP said [I don't want to use .new] ... **in the file**, which made me think OP didn't want to modify an existing file.

Comment: For me the title holds a lot of weight in how to read the rest of the question.  It is more of a reflection that the question is not clear, rather than your answer, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Add an option parser to your script and then properly instantiate the Print class from the option parser.  The option parser will handle the work of reading in the ARGV array and you can use the Print class in an OO manner as it is intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the allocate method to create an object of a class.

But I think you are really asking if you can create and call a class method.

`Print.disp(ARGV[0])` can definitely be done.

```
class Print
  def self.disp(something)
    puts something
  end
end

Print.disp(ARGV[0])
```

And you would call it like this:

`$ ruby display.rb Ross`

And it would output:

`Ross`

Answer (score 1):

You could call `ruby display.rb "ross"` if you weren't using a class, and just running straight Ruby code. For example, let's say your file looks like this:

```
puts ARGV[0]
```

You could now run this as `ruby display.rb "ross"` and your argument will get printed.

Another options would be to setup your function like this:

```
class Print
  def self.disp(yourinput)
    puts yourinput
  end
end
```

Which in this case, you could then call you function directly from the class, without needing to instantiate the class. For what you are trying to achieve, this may be your best solution.

```
Print.disp(ARGV[0])
```